# How can I configure AWS RDS Aurora reader to writer so that it works like multi master?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We are using AWS RDS Aurora for our application and using a read replica to read the data from the database.

We now want to use this read replica as the writer so that we can also write to this reader instance and data will be synced between them. Hence, to use it as multi-master replication.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I have tried to enable the read_only to false but the parameter is not modifiable.
Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-read-replica/

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/d5SCMQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the read_only parameter group setting for Aurora databases is not editable like it is for a MySQL parameter group.

Ref: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=746263&#746263